# iterate over pd dataframe to change integers to strings

Tags: python, loops

It's a very basic question but somehow my loop does not work. I have a pandas dataframe with two columns; path and word. A neural network predicted the outcome value in word, however this is still an integer. I wrote a for loop to replace those integers with words but there are no changes in the df. My df:

```
path    word
0   f7f172c01bec6a3e9a36dcafdf9e02e7df3522e4.wav    21
1   c17c29e392c57a9243ed52175568b40c04912194.wav    21
2   eea9239d4986b1f7dbffdcce76e0fce6e5f38ca8.wav    21
3   4fec4b033ba19d1ac875c0c062fda2869dbece73.wav    21
```

my loop:

```
for i in df['word']:
    if i == 0:
        i == "backward"
    elif i == 1:
        i == "bed"
    elif i == 2:
        i == "bird"
    elif i == 3:
        i == "cat"
    elif i == 4:
        i == "dog"
    elif i == 5:
        i == "down"
    elif i == 6:
        i == "eight"
    elif i == 7:
        i == "five"
    elif i == 8:
        i == "follow"
    elif i == 9:
        i == "forward"
    elif i == 10:
        i == "four"
    elif i == 11:
        i == "go"
    elif i == 12:
        i == "happy"
    elif i == 13:
        i == "house"
    elif i == 14:
        i == "learn"
    elif i == 15:
        i == "left"
    elif i == 16:
        i == "marvin"
    elif i == 17:
        i == "nine"
    elif i == 18:
        i == "no"
    elif i == 19:
        i == "off"
    elif i == 20:
        i == "on"
    elif i == 21:
        i == "one"
    elif i == 22:
        i == "right"
    elif i == 23:
        i == "seven"
    elif i == 24:
        i == "sheilla"
    elif i == 25:
        i == "six"
    elif i == 26:
        i == "stop"
    elif i == 27:
        i == "three"
    elif i == 28:
        i == "tree"
    elif i == 29:
        i == "two"
    elif i == 30:
        i == "up"
    elif i == 31:
        i == "visual"
    elif i == 32:
        i == "wow"
    elif i == 33:
        i == "yes"
    elif i == 34:
        i == "zero"
```

Comment: Please provide [minimal code to reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and indicate what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: My opinion is that you need to read about how to use pandas before even using it for complex scenarios such as neural network. As the answer mentions, map should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.map`:

```
#Add the rest of your mapping here (I just included a few)
mapping = {0: 'backward', 1: 'bed', 21: 'one', 22: 'right'}

df['word'] = df['word'].map(mapping)
```

Returns:

```
                                           path word
0  f7f172c01bec6a3e9a36dcafdf9e02e7df3522e4.wav  one
1  c17c29e392c57a9243ed52175568b40c04912194.wav  one
2  eea9239d4986b1f7dbffdcce76e0fce6e5f38ca8.wav  one
3  4fec4b033ba19d1ac875c0c062fda2869dbece73.wav  one
```